# Команда нажатия кнопки play/pause в плеере

Tags: winapi, c++

Сейчас во многих плеерах (Windows Media, PowerDVD итд) используется универсальная кнопка play/pause.

Подскажите, существует ли универсальный способ передать команду нажатия данной кнопки в окно приложения?

Comment: Немного не понятно о чём идёт речь. Вы хотите перехватить во внешнем приложении нажатие этой кнопки в медиаплеере или вы хотите перехватить нажатие аппаратной кнопки где-то на клавиатуре?

Answer (score 1):

Можно передавать один и тот же код, только надо создать флаг, который будет изменятся в зависимости от количества нажатий. А затем можно будет лишь проверить состояние этого флага.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы передаёте в своё приложение, то передавайте один и тот же код, а в приложении проверяйте если воспроизводиться что-то, то ставить на паузу, иначе - наоборот.
А если с мультимедийных клавиш на клавиатуре, то у меня, к примеру одна клавиша на паузу и воспроизведение.